# How to trigger map resize event after the angular.js ui-map directive is rendered?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

The [ui-map](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-map/) example works perfectly when using on a simple angular.js page. 
Now I'm using the ui-router and trying to display the map inside a view.
What happens is that the map tiles are only displayed on half of the map.
If I resize the window, the map is displayed correctly.

I think I have to trigger the Google Maps resize event once the view is rendered, but how?

```
google.maps.event.trigger(<myMapObject>, 'resize');
```

[image: ng-map not rendering correctly]

Answer (score 4):

Wait for a while before calling trigger, I had this same issue and found resolved here:

[AngularJS: map via Google Maps API v3 in a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444625/angularjs-map-via-google-maps-api-v3-in-a-tab)

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
},100);
```

Answer (score 1):

that work with angular 1.3.15

```
$timeout(function(){
         angular.forEach($scope.maps, function(index) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(index, 'resize');
          });
      }, 100);
    }
    $scope.maps = [];
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt, evtMap) {
          $scope.maps.push(evtMap);
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3P4iLTrog1ismFDUQNQe?p=preview

---

### other solutions

---

without adding $timeout you could also use $scope.$applyAsync() that runs code within the same digest cycle